# Using Extjs to generate excel Report

Tags: php, extjs, symfony-1.4, phpexcel

Currently in my UI (which is CRUD) of an employee, I add a button "Generate Excel Report" which means that when it's clicked, a file download dialog box will appear and will ask if I will download the file(together with the data from my postgre DB) to excel file.

My problem is that I haven't yet made my Ext. for this one. Several tries I've done but still it didn't work.

This is what I've tried so far:

From my 'actions.class.php':

```
public function executeGenerateEmployee(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../../../../lib/PhpExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
  // $con = Doctrine::getConnection("doctrine");    
  $con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();

  $sql = "SELECT e.id AS e__id, e.department AS e__department, (e.fname || ' ' || e.lname) AS e__0 FROM employees e ORDER BY e.id";

  $sheetTitle='Excel Report';
  $report_type='Programmers Group';
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $excel_report = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($excel_report))
  {
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $this->processExcel($excel_report,$objPHPExcel,$sheetTitle,$report_type);
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");   
    $writer->save("/tmp/excel_Report_2.xlsx");//directory

    die();
  }
    die('here');
 }
```

For my 'test.js':

```
 var generateItem = new Ext.Action ({
            text: 'Generate Excel Report',
            width: 60,
            enabled: true,
            handler: function(){        
            }               
        });
 GenerateReport: function() {},
```

I believed my codes from my actions.class.php file were right. I've done many test for that.
Only my Ext. is my problem. 
Could someone help me regarding this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: How does this fit together ? Is your php function called by submitting a form ? If so, submit a form with ExtJs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spending too much time to build this, we may have a ready solution for you. We have created a front-end XLS(X) and CSV import and export tool that you can use in ExtJS 4 applications with a few lines of code. The user just drags the file on the grid and done. We just launched it, here is a description: http://2gears.com/2014/08/ext-js-excel-import-export-easy/

As said, the import and export is done client side, so in applications with many concurrent users, this relieves the server from excessive load. In the next weeks also an import wizard will be added, that guides less capable users in importing files.

Hope it helps.